# C++ User Error, ignoring variable entries

Tags: c++

I got into a C++ class, and I have some experience with Java, but this program that I made just isn't working.

What I'm trying to do is display the largest, smaller, sum, difference, product, and ratio for the two values entered, but all it's giving me every time I enter is 0.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 0;
int greater_val = 0;
int smaller_val = 0;

cout << "Please enter one values, followed by enter, then another value.\n";
cin >> val1;
cin >> val2;

if (val1 > val2){
        val1 = greater_val;
        val2 = smaller_val;
    }
else if (val2 > val1){
        val2 = greater_val;
        val1 = smaller_val;
    }

cout << "Here are some statistics for the following values (" << val1 << " and " << val2 << "):";
cout << "\n\t Greatest value: " << greater_val;
cout << "\n\t Smallest value: " << smaller_val;
cout << "\n\t Sum: " << val1 + val2;
cout << "\n\t Difference: " << val1 - val2;
cout << "\n\t Product: " << val1 * val2;
cout << "\n\t Ratio: " << val1 / val2 << "\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have errors here:

```
if (val1 > val2){
    val1 = greater_val; //^^^should be greater_val = val1; same error apply below
    val2 = smaller_val;
}
else if (val2 > val1){
  //^^you probably don't need this if again, what if they are equal?
    val2 = greater_val;
    val1 = smaller_val;
}
```

Since `greater_val` and `smaller_val` are initialized as `0`, so with the code you have now, they are always zero.

Another point: you have to make sure that `val2` is not 0 when you do division.